# Am I binding events over and over again in this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, binding, event-handling

So I used this [totally awesome tool called Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2), which shows all the event handlers bound to an object - and I noticed that every time I clicked or played around with my object and checked the list of event handlers bound to it, there were and more every time. My problem is this one: [console.trace or stack trace to pinpiont the source of a bug in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937777/console-trace-or-stack-trace-to-pinpiont-the-source-of-a-bug-in-javascript#comment20979598_14937777) After using Visual Event and someone else's suggestion, I'm thinking my problem is that I'm probably binding the same handlers to the same events over and over again. Is there a way to unbind things regularly?

My application has a bunch of plugins connect to dynamically created `div`s. These `divs` can be resized and moved around the place. The application is a kind of editor, so users arrange these divs (which contain either images or text) in any design they like. If the user clicks on a div, it becomes "activated", while all other divs on the page get "deactivated". I have a bunch of related plugins, like `activateTextBox`, `initTextBox`, `deactivateTextBox`, `readyTextBox`, and so on. Whenever a div is first created, the `init` plugin is called once, just the first time after creation, like so:

```
$(mydiv).initTextBox();
```

But `readyTextBox` and `activateTextBox` and `deactivateTextBox` are called often, depending on other user events.

In `init`, I first use bind things like `resizable()` and `draggable()`, then I make the box "ready" for use

```
    $.fn.extend({
        initTextBox: function(){
        return this.each(function() {
               // lots of code that's irrelevant to this question
               $this.mouseenter(function(){ 
        if(!$this.hasClass('activated'))
            $this.readyTextBox();
         }
         $this.mouseleave(function(){ 
        if($this.hasClass('ready')){
            $this.deactivateTextBox(); 
                    $this.click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
                 });
                }
             });
     }); 
  });
```

Here's a simplified summary version of the `readyTextBox` plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        readyTextBox: function(){
        return this.each(function() {
               // lots of code that's irrelevant to this question
               $this.resizable({ handles: 'all', alsoResize: img_id});
               $this.draggable('enable');
               $this.on( "dragstop", function( event, ui )
               {/* some function */ });
               $this.on("resizestop", function( event, ui ){ /* another function */ });
               // and so on
});
```

Then there's `activateTextBox()`:

```
    $.fn.extend({
        activateTextBox: function(){
        return this.each(function() {
               // lots of code that's irrelevant to this question
               $this.resizable('option','disabled',true); //switch of resize & drag
               $this.draggable('option', 'disabled', true);
});
```

Then `deactivate`, where I turn on draggable and resizable again, using the code:

`$this.draggable('enable'); $this.resizable('option','disabled',false);`

These divs, or "textboxes" are contained within a bigger div called `content`, and this is the click code I have in `content`:

```
$content.click(function(e){
    //some irrelevant code
     if( /* condition to decide if a textbox is clicked */) 
     {  $(".textbox").each(function(){ //deactivate all except this
        if($(this).attr('id') != $eparent.attr('id')) 
            $(this).deactivateTextBox();
        });
        // now activate this particular textbox
        $eparent.activateTextBox();
             }
          });
```

This is pretty much the relevant code related to text boxes. Why is it that whenever I drag something around and then check Visual Event, there are more clicks and dragstops and mouseovers than before? Also, the more user interacts with the page, the longer the events take to complete. For example, I mouseout from a div, but the `move` cursor takes a *loooong* time to get back to default. I quit dragging, but everything gets stuck for a while before getting ready to take more user clicks, etc. So I'm guessing the problem has to be that I'm binding too many things to the same events need to be unbinding at some point? It gets so bad that draggable eventually stops working at some point. The textboxes just get stuck - they're still able to be resized, but dragging stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I binding events over and over

Yes. Have a look at your code:

```
$this.mouseenter(function(){ 
    …
    $this.mouseleave(function(){ 
        …
        $this.click(function(e){
            …
        });
    });
});
```

That means every time you mouseover the element, you add another leave handler. And when you leave the element, every of those handlers adds another click event.

I'm not sure what you want to do, but there are several options:

- bind the event handlers only once, and keep track of the current state with boolean variables etc.
- before binding, remove all other event handlers that are already bound. jQuery's [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) can help you to remove only those which your own plugin added.
- use the [`one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) that automatically unbinds a listener after firing it.

Comment: But `initTextBox()` is only called once, the first time. So how do I write the first binds? Or is it better to do something like `if(!bound(this.mouseleave)){//only then do the binding //}` (pseudocode)